# CSS top div to adjust height automatically

Tags: javascript, css, resize, kendo-ui

There're 2 divs - `top` and `bottom`.

The bottom should serve as a 'buttons pane', so visible and 'pinned' to bottom border at all times. root div is a Kendo UI Window div (see jsbin fiddle)

The problem is that the scrollbar is not being shown *ONLY* for the top div, but for 'buttons pane' as well. In the given jsbin resize down the window vertically, so the scrollbar appears:

http://jsbin.com/UrasoKi/3/edit

```
<style scoped>
    #top{
      min-height: 500px; 
      width: 100%; 
      background-color: blue
    }
    #bottom{
      height: 50px; 
      width: 100%; 
      background-color: green; 
      position: absolute; 
      bottom: 0px;
      /*kendo specific margin indentation, ignore*/
      margin: 0 0 0 -9px;
    }    
  </style>
 <div id="w">
  <div id="top">TOP PANE</div>
  <div id="bottom">BOTTOM PANE</div>
 </div>
```

I would like to achieve clear bottom div positioning with css. Scrollbar should appear for TOP panel ONLY.

Elements **MUST BE** positioned *INSIDE* `<div id='w'/>` in fiddle (because of telerik kendo window resize handles) AND **BE RESIZABLE**, so any extra volume would be given to the top pane. But extra divs could be added into it (into `div id="w"`)

I've been trying to play around for hours, something is missing.

Comment: ah ok my bad, I've updated my code to allow for this...

Comment: @NeilHibbert That's partially acceptable variant. The window is not just some edit-form, many things take place inside the window/top-pane, so it should have scrollbars to give access to all functionality at all times. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would tweak as follows to provide the sort of functionality you want:

```
<body>
  <style scoped>
    #top{
      height: 100%; 
      width: 100%; 

    }
    #bottom{
      height: 50px; 
      width: 100%; 
      background-color: green; 
      position: absolute; 
      bottom: 0px;
      /*kendo specific margin indentation, ignore*/
      margin: 0 0 0 -9px;
    }    
    #inner {
      overflow-y:scroll;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: blue
    }
  </style>
 <div id="w">
   <div id="top"><div id="inner">TOP PANE</div></div>  <div id="bottom">BOTTOM PANE</div>
 </div>
 <script>  
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#w').kendoWindow({
       width: '450px'
     });

     $('.k-window-content').css({'overflow':'hidden', scrollable: false })
   });
 </script>  
</body>
```

The tweaks include fixing the size of the Kendo Window and adding an inner div with fixed height and overflow-y scrolling for the top panel.

I hope this helps...

Comment: it MUST be resizable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `min-height: 500px;` is causing the window to show a scrollbar. You would want to put the two divs in another div with a fixed `min-height` and then give the two divs a fixed `min-height`

**Edit:**
Edited your fiddle, see if that is what you need.
http://jsbin.com/efOgoVE/10/edit

Comment: It's relatively what I ended up with and still trying to fix the scroll bar which just get lost behind the bottom pane.. Margins and paddings are tricky..